# Table border html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a bunch of tables now as and when I add table header `(<th>)`table row `<tr>` and add border to it there are multiple borders coming up. I mean say I have two table headers in a row so each and every th tag will add its own border but I just want want border between the two table header's (th).

```
<table>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td> </tr>
</table>
```

If you refer the above code and if I add borders to say th tag there will be 2 borders between header1 and header2. I just want 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem description is vague (in the future, please come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so that everyone can just copy'n'paste'n'run it to *see* what you exactly mean), but at least, a common solution to this "double border" problem is to add [`border-collapse: collapse`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp) property to the parent table in question:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Also see [this Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html) for several examples.

Answer (score 1):

Set `border-collapse:collapse` for both `table` and `th` in your CSS:

```
table, th, td { border-collapse:collapse }
```

Comment: It's not needed to define them separately in `th` and `td` as it's just inherited.

Comment: Yeah, but who knows what he has previously defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed to have 2 and only 2 th columns, and if I'm reading your question right that you just want a border between the two (i.e. in the middle of the two th tags), then just apply a border-right to the left th:

```
table
{
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
th.leftColumn
{
   border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

Markup

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th class="leftColumn">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

It's quick and dirty, but if you know you have only 2 columns it would work. Again this is assuming your question is that you want a border between two th cells, and nowhere else.